# AngularJS and Google Ajax Crawler

Tags: ajax, seo, angularjs

So basically I am trying to get angularJs Routes to look like this

```
 www.example.com/ajax.html#!product=1234
```

instead of like this

```
www.example.com/ajax.html#/product/1234
```

is there any hope?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just have to configure the [`$location` service](http://docs-angularjs-org-dev.appspot.com/guide/dev_guide.services.%24location) and call:

```
$locationProvider.hashPrefix("!")
```

Comment: heres a small discussion on it with some caveats on doing this though https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/angular/pMEvWSR8ffA

Comment: google said you don't need that anymore, you just have to turn on html push state in locationprovider and add <meta name="fragment" content="!"/> to head

Comment: @calmbird it does not prevent to use #! instead of the pushState API if you prefer to. BTW, configuring properly the HTTP server to serve capture with #! URLs is far easier.

Answer (score 1):

If your running a ruby app and want to adhere to the google ajax crawling scheme - there's a gem that implements the crawling scheme for any rack app....

```
gem install google_ajax_crawler
```

writeup of how to use it is at http://thecodeabode.blogspot.com.au/2013/03/backbonejs-and-seo-google-ajax-crawling.html, source code at  https://github.com/benkitzelman/google-ajax-crawler

Comment: unfortunately yes as its a ruby gem which runs as rack middleware, so only those ajax heavy apps running a ruby rack backend (i.e. rails / sinatra)